# How to embedded exe file into png file such that when png file open then exe file also open with png?

Tags: .net

No code yet. I have used binary and base64 to embedded exe and png file into png. But none of these methods works for me. Because when I run png file exe is not run. I don't know why. I need help in this project

```
 saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG (*.png)|*.png|JPG (*.jpg*)|*.jpg*";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
        string exeString = Convert.ToBase64String(exe);

        string pading = "";
        while (imageString.Contains("="))
        {
            imageString = imageString.Remove(imageString.Length - 1);
            pading = pading + "=";
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Convert.FromBase64String(imageString + exeString + "="));
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Comment: If that would work, the internet would explode.

Comment: mean?? I am working on my project that's why I need this method

Comment: .png file is an image format.  I suppose you could put a payload in it, but another program would need to execute that.  Are you trying to target something in particular here?

Comment: No I want to put self execute-able code like command in png file that will run itself.Can we do this?

Comment: @MobeenGhaffar No.

Comment: @MechMK1 then how can I do any idea about this?

Comment: I'm really not trying to be critical here, but there isn't an easy way to say this.  What you are trying to do just doesn't make sense and isn't possible.  Your question demonstrates that you are very new to this - which is no problem - we were all new once.  However, what you are trying to do is not at all easy, and likely impossible.  Rather than trying to focus on this particular task, I think you should just continue learning and experimenting.

Comment: @MechMK1 Well, something like this was possible for Android until last February... (See CVE-2019-1986, CVE-2019-1987, and CVE-2019-1988)

Comment: It might help if you explain your project.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60195937/how-to-read-two-files-exe-and-image-into-one-image-such-that-when-image-file

Answer (score 3):

A file is nothing but a set of bytes (or 0s and 1s) that a certain program (a file itself) knows how to read and possibly edit.

While a program runs (process), it interacts with the kernel of the operating system and, through it, devices such as CPU, RAM, disks. If it runs on a VM, there are additional interactions with the hypervisor (KVM, ESX, Virtualbox, Xen).

The point is, a file is nothing special from a security standpoint *by itself*. So, what you're looking for might be done if you find a vulnerability in how that file interacts with

1) the program(s). Sometimes there are vulnerabilities in the way specific file formats are defined, but more often it's a matter of specific implementations.

2) the operating system

3) hypervisor (if any)

4) hardware.

If you want to find some vulnerability like this yourself, be prepared for a lot of study. It is in no way an easy task.

Comment: I would add `5) the user` to the list. This starts with users simply executing untrusted executables or scripts and ends in certain applications that intentionally support potentially dangerous actions embedded in their file formats that an uninformed user is overlooking (such as MS Office macros).